# Find average score based on reviews - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, weighted-average

I have dataframe like this.

```
    UserID  Review      MovieID
0   10112   Good        MOV001
1   10112   Excellent   MOV002
2   10112   Average     MOV003
3   10113   Good        MOV001
4   10113   Bad         MOV002
5   10113   Good        MOV003
6   10113   Excellent   MOV004
7   10114   Good        MOV001
8   10114   Bad         MOV002
9   10114   Good        MOV003
10  10114   Excellent   MOV004
```

I've changed the reviews to int values.

```
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Average'] = 2
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Good'] = 3
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Excellent'] = 5
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Very Good'] = 4
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Okay'] = 1
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Bad'] = 0
movies
```

Now my dataframe will look like this,

```
        UserID  Review      MovieID
    0   10112   3           MOV001
    1   10112   5           MOV002
    2   10112   2           MOV003
    3   10113   3           MOV001
    4   10113   0           MOV002
    5   10113   3           MOV003
    6   10113   5           MOV004
    7   10114   3           MOV001
    8   10114   0           MOV002
    9   10114   3           MOV003
    10  10114   5           MOV004
```

Now how can I find the average rating for each movie? 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Create dictionary and then use `map`

Comment: Like `df.Review = df.Review.map({'Bad':0, 'Okay':1})`